# BASH scripting: taking in multiple flags

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I have this issue where I am doing a menu sort of program where users are supposed to type in different numbers depending on what operation(s) the want to do.
Right now I need to take in multiple flags to be placed in a command, but I can't seem to get it to work.
Catch: I cannot type in the flags directly into one variable and I will probably have to have this case list to be able to quit at will)

```
function fileCpy {
   printf "Choices:\n1. Interactive copy, answer yes/no before doing the copy: \n2. Make backups of existing destination files\n3. Preserve file attributes\n4. Do a recursive copy\n0. Return to main menu\n"
        #read choices
    read $a
    read $b
    read $c
    for choices in $choice ; do
      case "$choices" in
          1)
        a=-i ;;
          2)
        b=--backup ;;
          3)
        c=-p ;;
          #4)
        #4= -R -v;;
          0)
         main;;
    esac
    echo "$a"
    echo "$b"
    echo "$c"
    printf "\nType the name of the file you wish to copy/backup: "
    read $fl1
    printf "\nType the destination file: "
    read $des1
    cp $a $b $c $fl1 $des1
  done
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that `read $a` etc is wrong: you should write `read a` if you need the read at all.  As it stands, the value read is stored in the variable with the name stored in `$a`.

Another problem is that it is far from clear to the innocent user that they're supposed to enter 3 lines of information before the script will continue, but the three `read` lines force that.

Another problem is that you don't read into `$choice` (via `read choice`) so the `for` loop has nothing to do.

Another problem is that your script will inherit the values of any environment variables that happen to be the same as the names of the variables you're using.

Another problem is that you don't quote the file names. It mostly won't matter unless you have a name that contains spaces or other similarly awkward characters.

A cosmetic issue is that the `printf` statement is ridiculously long.  Use one `printf` per line.  Or use `echo`.  Stuff that scrolls off the RHS of the page is bad (though I don't regard 80 characters as a fixed length for lines, there's a quadratic penalty for lines that are longer than 80 — as (length-80)<sup>2</sup> increases, the pain of the longer line goes up.

At another level altogether, the interface is modestly grotesque. As an exercise in shell scripting, it makes sense.  As an exercise in how to design good shell scripts, it is a very bad design.

A design that might make sense is:

1. Set variables to empty: `a=""; b=""; c="";` etc.
2. Offer a range of choices similar to those given now, but add an option to execute the command, and another to abandon ship.
3. Have a loop that reads choices, and sets flags.
4. When the user chooses execute, exit the loop and prompt for the file names.
5. If all's well, execute the command.

Note that you should check that the `read` commands work; if they don't, fail safe (don't damage anything).

---

Putting all those together (with some slight differences, but the same overall effect — witness the use of [`local`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Builtins) for the variables):

```
fileCpy()
{
    local a b c file dest
    echo "Choices:"
    echo "0. Return to main menu"
    echo "1. Interactive copy, answer yes/no before doing the copy"
    echo "2. Make backups of existing destination files"
    echo "3. Preserve file attributes"
    echo "4. Do a recursive copy"
    echo "5. Execute the copy"
    while printf "Your choice: " && read choice
    do
        [ -z "$choice" ] && return 1 # Empty input - failure
        case "$choice" in
        (0) return 0;;
        (1) a="-i";;
        (2) b="--backup";;
        (3) c="-p";;
        (4) d="-R";;
        (5) break;;
        (*) echo "Unrecognized response ($choice); please enter 0..5";;
        esac
    done
    [ "$choice" != 5 ] && return 1 # EOF - failure
    printf "Type the name of the file you wish to copy/backup: "
    read file
    [ -z "$file" ] && return 1 # Empty file name - failure
    printf "Type the name of the destination file/directory:   "
    read dest
    [ -z "$dest" ] && return 1 # Empty file name - failure
    cp $a $b $c "$file" "$dest"
}
```

Test code:

```
echo "a=$a b=$b c=$c file=$file dest=$dest"
if fileCpy
then : OK
else echo "Failed"
fi
echo "a=$a b=$b c=$c file=$file dest=$dest"
```

The last block is a simple test harness. It reports on the values of the variables used inside the function, runs the function, reports if the function failed, and re-echoes the variables to demonstrate that they've not been set.

I would not use that interface unless you paid me to do so, but it more or less meets the goal of a training exercise.

Comment: Thanks for the input but I do have some questions:
How would a loop like point 3 look like? That is basically what I do not know.
Second, should the ending cp $a $b $c $fl1 $des1 work? 
The error that I am currently getting (after doing some modifications, i.e changing the read variables after your example and adding " " around the text strings in each case.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do menu, you can use `select` construct (or `case/esac`). See [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testbranch.html) for info